# php pattern matching

Tags: php, pattern-matching

I want to get the part of the string before the last occurance of "-",

for example,

```
$string1 = 'a-b-c-de-f-gfgh';
```

I want to get this part returned: a-b-c-de-f. Of course, I don't know the length of the last part.

What is the easy way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: So many ways, what have you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo substr ($string1, 0, strrpos ($string1, '-'));
```

strrpos() finds the last occurrence of a substring, - in this case, and substr() splits the original string from the 0th character until the nth character as defined by strrpos()

Answer (score 1):

Use [strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strrpos.php) to get position of last "-" and [substr()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php) it:

```
echo substr($string1, 0, strrpos($string1, "-"));
```

Answer (score 1):

get the last occurrence of `-` using `$x =  strrpos($string1,'-');` 
then use `substr()` to return the decired string from 0 to $x

```
 echo substr ($string1, 0, $x);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other posters:

```
preg_match('/(.*)-[^-]+/', 'a-b-c-de-f-gfgh', $result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a-b-c-de-f-gfgh-a
    [1] => a-b-c-de-f-gfgh
)
```

Though I like Jeroens solution more.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove that last part:

```
$string = preg_replace("|-[^-]+$|", "", $string);
```